# Counting the number of times the value 1 appears in each row of a VCF converted to a pandas data frame

Tags: pandas, dataframe, count

I am trying to count the number of times the value 1 appears in each row of a Vcf converted into a data frame.

```
#CHROM  POS ID  REF ALT QUAL    FILTER  INFO    FORMAT  A01_01  A01_02  A01_03  A01_04  A01_05
chr01   27915   27915   T   C   .   .   .   GT  0   1   0   0   1
chr01   28323   28323   G   A   .   .   .   GT  0   1   0   0   1
chr01   28652   28652   G   T   .   .   .   GT  0   1   0   0   1
chr01   29667   29667   C   A   .   .   .   GT  0   1   0   0   1
chr01   30756   30756   C   G   .   .   .   GT  0   1   0   0   1
chr01   31059   31059   G   A   .   .   .   GT  0   1   0   0   1
chr01   31213   31213   G   A   .   .   .   GT  0   1   0   0   1
chr01   31636   31636   T   C   .   .   .   GT  0   1   0   0   1
chr01   31756   31756   C   T   .   .   .   GT  0   1   0   0   1
chr01   31976   31976   C   T   .   .   .   GT  0   1   0   0   1
```

this is what the VCF looks like in excel. but with more rows and columns, the extra columns are just more genotypes and the rows are more positions and alleles. 
I am trying to count them using a python script. I have successfully converted the Vcf into a pandas data frame using data = pd.read_table("....")
I know I should use the count function, but I am unable to get it to count in the rows that I want. The eventual goal is to make a histogram that shows the frequency of each allele. (1 means it is there 0 means it is not) so I want to count the number of times 1 appears in each row and make a histogram out of the frequencies. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways I know of to do this, both using the [sum function](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sum.html) in pandas. It allows you to take the sum of every numeric type cell in the row (so if you have, say, a column of ID strings, which it looks like you probably do, it'll skip those). If the only numerics in your data are 1s and 0s or you can easily remove any columns with other numerics, that'll do you.

I can't really parse your example data, so let's make some up for an example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,2, size=(100,4)), columns=list('ABCD'))
```

With this data, if you want to add an additional column that's the sum of each row:

```
df['Sum'] = df.sum(1, skipna=True, numeric_only=True)
```

Or you can just assign that to a variable itself. Either way you can then give those counts to your preferred plotting package to make your histogram.

If your data is more complex and you have numerics other than 1, you can take the intermediate step of creating a dataframe of booleans first, so if the value of a cell is 1 it's True and otherwise it's False. So let's make another random dataframe:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,10, size=(100,4)), columns=list('ABCD'))
```

This one is random ints 0-9. Now let's make that intermediate dataframe:

```
df2_bool = (df2 == 1)
```

Now we can do that sums thing again:

```
df2['Sum'] = df2_bool.sum(1, skipna=True, numeric_only=True)
```

Now you've got counts!

There's likely a better way to do this but this is how I've been doing it and it's served me pretty well.

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, you can do it this way:

```
In [45]: df.filter(like='A01').sum(axis=1)
Out[45]:
0    2
1    2
2    2
3    2
4    2
5    2
6    2
7    2
8    2
9    2
dtype: int64


In [44]: df.filter(like='A01')
Out[44]:
   A01_01  A01_02  A01_03  A01_04  A01_05
0       0       1       0       0       1
1       0       1       0       0       1
2       0       1       0       0       1
3       0       1       0       0       1
4       0       1       0       0       1
5       0       1       0       0       1
6       0       1       0       0       1
7       0       1       0       0       1
8       0       1       0       0       1
9       0       1       0       0       1
```